# Formula that will take a number in a cell, and then add that number to itself -1, until itself -1 = 0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need a formula that will take a number in a cell, and then add that number to itself -1, until itself -1 = 0.  For example, if the number were 5, the formula would be:

5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

I could do this pretty easily in a for loop, but I hoping to avoid messing with sheets scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Assuming the number in question is 38 minus whatever is in cell B15, the following formula works perfectly:

`=((38-$B15)*$B15) + ((38-$B15) * (38-$B15)/2) - (38-$B15)/2`

Answer (score 0):

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B1))))`

...assuming the start number is in B1.

Essentially, this creates a reference to a range with as many rows as your start number, then uses SUM to add the row number property of each row.